# install ROS groovy and Hydro at the same time

Tags: ros, installation, catkin, ros-hydro, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For different projects, I need to have Groovy and Hydro installed in my system. How do I use the catkin_ws and other packages? Do I have separate catkin_ws? Can I rename them separately like catkin_ws_g and catkin_ws_h, or will it create accessibility problems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133041/install-ros-groovy-and-hydro-at-the-same-time/) by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure, that's no problem. Just install both.

You'll need to have different workspaces though as the code in there will be compiled and linked against the specific ROS distribution.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2